# How do I update/set an array using variables as index in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

How do I update/set the `quiz_score` array by using `qnNumber` as index in mongodb?

query

```
let modifier = {}
modifier["course_learn_list.$.quiz_score." + qnNumber] = selectedAnsNum
Meteor.users.update({
    _id: Meteor.userId(),
    "course_learn_list.course_id": courseId
}, {
    $set: {
        modifier
    }
})
```

mongo data

```
{
  "_id": "WsCS7CpeRymtjEjRi",
  "course_learn_list": [
    {
      "course_id": "JPaW6YGGoe8xiCjpJ",
      "class_id": "PbRHjWpGsvuQWogJF",
      "quiz_score": [
        -1,
        -1,
        -1,
        -1
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Typo. You meant `{ "$set": modifier }` without wrapping the variable in curlies `{}`. It's already an object with the correct key and value set.

Comment: yes you are right. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
let modifier = {}
modifier["course_learn_list.$.quiz_score." + qnNumber] = selectedAnsNum
Meteor.users.update({
   _id: Meteor.userId(),
    "course_learn_list.course_id": courseId
}, {
    $set: modifier
})
```